# Magento 2.3, built in page_cache asked to be refreshed manually, can I automate this?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm running Magento 2.3, the built in page_cache asks to be refreshed manually, how can I automate this?

Should I use a Magento2 cron job?

I created this module, [magento2-AutoRefreshCache](https://github.com/techzilla/magento2-AutoRefreshCache), and made it available via composer [cyberpunkspike/module-autorefreshcache](https://packagist.org/packages/cyberpunkspike/module-autorefreshcache).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for Magento 2 you have to setup a cron job to do any of the cache refreshing automatically.

I'm not a Magento developer so I can't tell you how good your custom module is. I have my cron jobs running the 'old fashion way' by SSH'ing to my linux server, running "crontab -e" and having the below code at the bottom:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento indexer:reindex
0 7 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento cache:clean
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Comment: Can you check my module, and see if it's correct?

Comment: No... wait a second, then what is `backend_clean_cache`?